# How can I get the UTC time, add a user-defined offset and then convert it to Unix (epoch) format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

On `guildMemberAdd`, it'll give me a Unix timestamp (`member.joinedTimestamp`) that I then use `toFormattedString()` to make it readable. However, there is no such thing as `member.leftTimestamp`.

Just to clarify:
`guildMemberAdd` logs `Join: 06/16/20 17:31:09`.
`guildMemberRemove` logs `Left: 06/16/20 10:47:50`.
So, I *think* I have to get the UTC time, add an offset (in this case, -5 hours for EST) and then convert it to a Unix timestamp but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function (length, character) { 
    return new Array(length - this.length + 1).join(character || ' ') + this; 
};
Date.prototype.toFormattedString = function() {
  return [String(this.getMonth() + 1).padLeft(2, '0'),
    String(this.getDate()).padLeft(2, '0'),
    String(this.getFullYear()).substr(2, 2)
  ].join("/") + " " + [String(this.getHours()).padLeft(2, '0'),
    String(this.getMinutes()).padLeft(2, '0'), String(this.getSeconds()).padLeft(2, '0')
  ].join(":");
};

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome');
  if (!channel) return;
  var timestamp = new Date(member.joinedTimestamp);
  console.log('Join: ' + timestamp.toFormattedString());
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome');
  if (!channel) return; 
  var timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // this is what I need to change
  console.log('Left: ' + timestamp.toFormattedString());
});
```

Comment: Working with datetimes in multiple timezones is tricky enough without the additional problem of only "thinking" you know your goal. Only once you define exactly what to do will you (or we) be in a position to think about how to do it.

Comment: [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) and [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close! `new Date().getTime()` returns in milliseconds, all we need to do to get a Unix timestamp is divide by 1000. Then round it off to get a nice clean timestamp. `Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);`. Good luck on your project!

Comment: I understand how to get a Unix timestamp, the thing I'm confused about is how to add an offset to it. It currently gives me a GMT time, when I need EST.

Comment: Unix timestamps are always UTC hence the definition "Unix time (also known as POSIX time or epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds."